# HTML email Button to call AWS API Gateway

Tags: python, html, email

I'm new at this and have been searching to find a resolution. I am creating a HTML email and I want to include a button at the end of the email to make a post call to a AWS API gateway. The creator of the API gateway has provided me the proper format, https://t08brd90af.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/nonprod/OrphanedAccounts?cloud=OrphanedAccounts&users=some.user@domain.com

I have tested the API call in postman and it works as it should. I get a positive response from the API gateway when I test it in postman.

Now I want to include a button in the email so the user can press it to kick off a lambda function via the API gateway. I have tried various "suggestions" from chatGPT and other AI's but with every suggestion when I press the button it opens up a new tab in my browser and I get an error, {"message": "Unsupported Media Type"}.

What code do I need to include in my HTML email that will provide me the function I am looking for?

TIA..

This is my last test that I tried.

```
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>This is the body of your email.</p>
        <p>
            To trigger the process, click the button below:
        </p>
            <form action="{api_gateway_url}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cloud" value="OrphanedAccounts">
            <input type="hidden" name="users" value="some.user@domain.com">
            <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
        </form
        <script>
            function makeApiCall() {{
                var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
                var data = new FormData(form);
                var apiRequest = new Request("{api_gateway_url}", {{
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)),
                    headers: {{
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                    }}
                }});
                fetch(apiRequest)
                    .then(response => {{
                        if (response.ok) {{
                            console.log("API call successful");
                            console.log("Response:", response.json());
                        }} else {{
                            console.log("API call failed");
                            console.log("Status Code:", response.status);
                            console.log("Response:", response.json());
                        }}
                    }})
                    .catch(error => {{
                        console.log("API call failed:", error);
                    }});
            }}
        </script>
    </body>
```